# segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to enter a for loop

Tags: c, eclipse, for-loop, segmentation-fault

my code is:

```
int main (void){

    int i,j,k,x;
    .
    .
    .
    printf("before loop\n");

    for (x=0; x<5; x++){
        printf("loop %d",x);
        //do something...
    }
    .
    .
    .
return 0;
}
```

It prints "before loop" and then gives a segmentation fault (core dumped), thus doesn't print any of the "loop #".
Has anyone encountered that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Have you tried catching the crash in a debugger? Where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables? Have you tried using a memory debugger such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? What optimization flags (if any) do you use when building? Finally, without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's really impossible to properly help you.

Comment: You get this because of some bug in the code not present in the question...

Comment: It would be a very good idea to change: `printf("loop %d",x);` to `printf("loop %d\n",x);`  so the output is displayed immediately, one entry per line on the terminal, rather than sitting in the stdout buffer until either the buffer overflows, or an input operation is performed or some other code outputs a '\n'.

Answer (score -1):

I did find the problem, although I don't understand why it solves it.
In the inner print (inside the loop) - there needs to be a "\n" at the end:

```
for (x=0; x<5; x++){
    printf("loop %d\n",x);
.
.
.
```

Thanks all for trying to help.

Comment: you must have changed something else, because the originally posted `printf()` statement will not cause a seg fault event.  I.E. there is some undefined behavior else where in the code.  Strongly suggest posting the whole function so we can help you find the actual source of the problem.

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are by default line buffered, which means that writing on them with `putc()`, `puts()`, `fprintf()` are held in a buffer until a `\n` is encountered or the buffer is full. Calling `fflush()` spills also the buffer. The `setvbuf()` function allows to set the mode of a stream. It can be set to 'not buffered', 'line buffered' or 'fully buffered'.

Comment: and your segfault is probably related to something else. Your excerpt doesn't contain any "offensive" code.